# Typescript definition file for javascript class throws runtime error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

I have a file Messaging.d.ts.  It defines a couple of classes written in javascript.  The definition in the TS file is written as follows:

```
declare module 'Messaging' {
export default class DisplayMessageManager {
    AddMainMessage(message: string, alertCssClass: string): void;
    DontShowTipAgain(alertID: string): void;
    CloseTip(alertID: string, showAlertTime: number): void;
    TogglePanelDirty(panelID: string, isDirty: boolean, originalState: string): void;
}

}

declare module 'MessagingConstants' {
export default class Constants {
    //Bootstrap Alert Classes
    bsSuccess: string;
    bsWarning: string;
    bsDanger: string;
    bsInfo: string;
    bsDefault: string;
    bsPrimary: string;
}
}
```

When I import this in my app.ts file (in the same folder) I use:

```
import DisplayMessageManager  from 'Messaging';
import Constants from 'MessagingConstants';
```

and then:

```
messageManager: DisplayMessageManager = new DisplayMessageManager();
messageConstants: Constants = new Constants();
```

later I use:

```
        this.messageManager.AddMainMessage('test', this.messageConstants.bsSuccess);
```

This all compiles correctly.  However, when I run the code the error in the console tells me that it cannot find the file 'Messaging.js'.  I did not think that a typescript definition file needed to compile into a javascript file.  What am I doing wrong to get these external javascript classes to work?

Comment: I did what I feel like is sort of a hack.  I declared the variables     var gMessageManager = new DisplayMessageManager(); var gConstants = new Constants(); in my javascript file.  I then used declare var gMessageManager: any; and declare var gConstants: any; in my definition file.  Works the way I expect now but doesn't seem to be what Typescript definitions are intended for.

Comment: Is there only a `Messaging.d.ts`? Is there no `Messaging.js`?

Comment: That is correct.  The js file was named differently and had other code in it.  Does the original js file name need to correspond to the definition file name?  Seems like it should just see it in the global javascript scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using non-relative paths (i.e. `"Messaging"` instead of `"./Messaging"`), if you're using CommonJS, this means you should have a `node_modules/Messaging/` and `node_modules/MessagingConstants/`.

I'm not sure if that's actually what you want. What you may've meant to do is create the following two declaration files to reflect the exact shape of your local `.js` files

`Messaging.d.ts`:

```
export default class DisplayMessageManager {
    AddMainMessage(message: string, alertCssClass: string): void;
    DontShowTipAgain(alertID: string): void;
    CloseTip(alertID: string, showAlertTime: number): void;
    TogglePanelDirty(panelID: string, isDirty: boolean, originalState: string): void;
}
```

`MessagingConstants.d.ts`:

```
export default class Constants {
    //Bootstrap Alert Classes
    bsSuccess: string;
    bsWarning: string;
    bsDanger: string;
    bsInfo: string;
    bsDefault: string;
    bsPrimary: string;
}
```

And then include them like so:

```
import DisplayMessageManager  from './Messaging';
import Constants from './MessagingConstants';
```

Comment: Just tried this route.  Here is the error I'm still getting:  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:65421/app/Messaging.js
 Error loading http://localhost:65421/app/Messaging.js as "./Messaging" from http://localhost:65421/app/app.js

Comment: I changed the name of the file to match my JS file and then put both classes in the MyJSNamedFile.d.ts file with no default classes.  Works as expected now.  I didn't realize it would try to map file names in that fashion.

Comment: Since I mentioned above that these .d.ts files need to match the exact shape of your .js files, would you say that this sufficiently answered your question?

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that's what you meant by exact shape.  Sure thing.